# Dynamically change User control on drop down change event in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web page with a Dropdown control like this:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="TypeDrp" runat="server" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="LoadCorrectForm" AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <br />

  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

  </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

i want to dynamically load usercontrol on the same page on dropdown OnSelectedIndexChanged

i tried the below code, but it not seems to be working

```
    string filename = TypeDrp.SelectedValue;
    UserControl userControl;
    switch (filename)
    {
        case "XTypeForm.ascx":
            UserControl ctrl = 
    (XTypeForm)LoadControl("NewFolder1/XTypeForm.ascx");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
            break;
    }
```

not able to figure out whats wrong?
can someone help me out with the other approach to deal this functionalty?

Comment: have you add add a reference directive in your .aspx file?? `<%@ Reference Control="~/NewFolder1/XTypeForm.ascx">`

Comment: What is "not working"? Is there an error? Does the UC not get loaded? Is the OnSelectedIndexChanged not working?

Comment: @Curiousdev, you do not need a reference directive if you add Controls dynamically with code.